# What is the inside?

Tags: algebraic-manipulation, implementation-details

What is the inside of the Mathematica command, solve, for a system of equations like the following?

$$\eqalign{
(x +2\phantom{3} z)^2 + (y +\phantom{3} w)^2 &= 52\cr 
(x + 30z)^2 + (y + 3w)^2 &= 296\cr
}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for any helpful answers!

Comment: Here is a good place to start: https://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Solve.html

Comment: @bills: I am just wondering, how would Mathematica solve the system? Thanks!

Comment: There is a considerable amount of information [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ComplexPolynomialSyste‌​ms.html). In brief, a Groebner basis is constructed in lexicographic term order, root extraction is done on the first polynomial, with back substitution in subsequent polynomials.

Comment: PS Generally one gets better answers when the query contains actual cut-and-pasteable examples or code.

Answer (score 10):

The precise details of the *Mathematica* engine are proprietary, therefore no one will be able to legally post a full answer to your question.  The best information I am aware of comes from the [Notes on Internal Implementation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation.html#23195) tutorial.  Excerpts from that document:

- For linear equations, Gaussian elimination and other methods of linear algebra are used.
- For single polynomial equations, Solve uses explicit formulas up to degree four, attempts to reduce polynomials using Factor and Decompose, and recognizes cyclotomic and other special polynomials.
- For systems of polynomial equations, Solve constructs a Gröbner basis.
- Solve and GroebnerBasis use an efficient version of the Buchberger algorithm.
- For non-polynomial equations, Solve attempts to change variables and add polynomial side conditions.
- The code for Solve and related functions is about 500 pages long.
- For polynomial systems, Reduce uses cylindrical algebraic decomposition for real domains and Gröbner basis methods for complex domains.
- With algebraic functions, Reduce constructs equivalent purely polynomial systems. With transcendental functions, Reduce generates polynomial systems composed with transcendental conditions, then reduces these using functional relations and a database of inverse image information. With piecewise functions, Reduce does symbolic expansion to construct a collection of continuous systems.
- CylindricalDecomposition uses the Collins-Hong algorithm with Brown-McCallum projection for well-oriented sets and Hong projection for other sets. CAD construction is done by Strzebonski's genealogy-based method using validated numerics backed up by exact algebraic number computation. For zero-dimensional systems Gröbner basis methods are used.
- GenericCylindricalDecomposition uses a simplified version of the CAD algorithm that uses a simpler projection operator and constructs only cells with rational number sample points.
- For Diophantine systems, Reduce solves linear equations using Hermite normal form, and linear inequalities using Contejean-Devie methods. For univariate polynomial equations, it uses an improved Cucker-Koiran-Smale method, while for bivariate quadratic equations, it uses Hardy-Muskat-Williams methods for ellipses and classical techniques for Pell and other cases. Reduce includes specialized methods for about 25 classes of Diophantine equations, including the Tzanakis-de Weger algorithm for Thue equations.
- Reduce and related functions use about 350 pages of Mathematica code and 1400 pages of C code.

Comment: "[…] therefore no one will be able to legally post a full answer to your question." Well, Wolfram would be able to legally post one. Not that I'd expect them to do it.